# Is there any PHP Equivalent of the JAVA SecretKeyFactory to make a login system?

Tags: java, php, mysql, sha1, salt

(It's my first post here.)

I'm programming a minecraft server website and I want to put a login system.
My minecraft server (**BungeeCord**) is using "**BungeeAuth**" to ask players to set a password to their accounts.

The BungeeAuth's password is stored in my Mysql server with two main colomns : "*playername*" and "*password*".

I want to be able to log in with this password on my website.

The password is hashed strangly. I decided to decompile "BungeeAuth" to see how it works.

This is the librairies :

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
```

This is the code :

```
public boolean validatePassword(String originalPassword, String storedPassword)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException {
    String parts[] = storedPassword.split(":");
    int iterations = Integer.parseInt(parts[0]);
    byte salt[] = fromHex(parts[1]);
    byte hash[] = fromHex(parts[2]);
    PBEKeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(originalPassword.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, hash.length * 8);
    SecretKeyFactory skf = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    byte testHash[] = skf.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    int diff = hash.length ^ testHash.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < hash.length && i < testHash.length; i++) {
        diff |= hash[i] ^ testHash[i];
    }

    return diff == 0;
}

private static byte[] fromHex(String hex)
        throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    byte bytes[] = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        bytes[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(hex.substring(2 * i, 2 * i + 2), 16);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

I understanded that the salt is random and the password is crypted in **SHA1** (*PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1*).

Is there any function in PHP to do the same ?
I've tried *hash_hmac('sha1', ..., $salt)* but it seems to be different.

Comment: Can you post a hash password in you have in your database?? By the way according to java documentation about SecretKeyFactory it uses DES encryption algorithm.

Comment: The mdp is "exemplemdp". In my database I get : 1000:5b42403739623935316666:b71c3174cebbdaae3eaa1136bf691c1d53e36908f78fa821010df9b0c1a6bb34f175ce95b18aa4b468ff22b958d4ff8f13c54bb9dbd19dfb055b5e503565de29

Comment: The SQL : INSERT INTO `BungeeAuth` (`id`, `playername`, `password`, `pwtype`) VALUES
(2, 'pseudo', '1000:5b42403739623935316666:b71c3174cebbdaae3eaa1136bf691c1d53e36908f78fa821010df9b0c1a6bb34f175ce95b18aa4b468ff22b958d4ff8f13c54bb9dbd19dfb055b5e503565de29', 1);

Comment: What function you use to generate salts?